# jQuery selector performance - One statement vs two

Tags: jquery

Is there any performance difference between using two separate calls to hide two elements, or would it be more/less efficient to use only 1 statement?  Is there any practical difference?

```
$('#container1').hide();
$('#container2').hide();
```

vs:

```
$('#container1, #container2').hide();
```

Also, which do you think is more readable?

Comment: It doesn’t matter in this case.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies, very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a minor performance difference in that the same delegate is being called on both elements, but this is a very, **very** minor memory allocation.  Any extra lines of code also mean more work for the javascript interpreter and work for the browser...that's more of a difference than anything, but still an infinitesimally small difference.

Short answer:  the second one is *slightly* faster/uses less memory, it's so insanely insignificant you probably couldn't measure without looping tens of thousands of times.

Comment: @Nick - Out of curiosity, will both of these result in two DOM traversals, or will the second version accomplish both in one traversal?

Comment: @patrick - Well both have 2 "traversals", but that's not a great term when using the `#ID` selector, in that case you're asking the browser to return the element directly (usually from an internal hash table, which is why it's so fast).  You're calling a method, getting an element...so you're not doing any traversing/crawling/searching when using an ID.  When using multiple selectors, Sizzle is just taking them and fetching them 1 by 1 adding them to the collection (optimizing where possible, of course)  With respect to **fetching the ID element**, both perform the same amount of work.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I always wondered how elements were acquired. I somehow assumed that full DOM traversals were needed for selection. Glad to hear that's not the case. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, it would not make a practical difference. You're still looking for two specific id's in the DOM.

As far as readibility goes, I would keep them in one statement, as long as they are logically grouped.

However, if your next line is something that operates on container2 sepearately, then separate the 2. No need to do extra traversals. For example:

```
//2 dom traversals
$('#container1').hide();
$('#container2').hide().html(some_html);
```

is faster than

```
//3 dom traversals
$('#container1, #container2').hide();
$('#container2').html(some_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter from an efficiency standpoint.  I think the second option is better for readability, if you don't need to attach separate events to one of the elements: `$('#containter1').hide().html('foo');` ...and no the other element.

Answer (score 0):

Both are pretty much the same, the second is a few characters shorter if that's a consideration that's important for you.